# why is my contact page confirming in a new page?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, contact-form

I'll admit right off the bat that I am less than an amateur when it comes to php. In fact, I'm working on a portfolio for a mid-level web design course right now. One of the requirements is that I have a styled, functional contact form, and I've been searching high and low for a free one that neatly drops into my code and that I can understand enough to style it.

I feel like I'm close with this one, *but when it gives the confirmation for your message going through, it opens in a new page*.

I'm hoping for everything to happen within the div where I've placed my contact form, but... again, I'm a little new and I'm not sure what to modify or how in order to get that happening. Also, I'm not sure if this conforms to the usual means through which people ask for advice here, but I'll just link to the site with the contact form I'm trying to use:

http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php

Any tips, including  your favorite contact forms, are welcome!

Comment: The new page thing is normal unless you submit the form via AJAX*, which will more than likely be outside of your skill level. (*There are some other tricks you can use, like targeting an iframe to render the thanks result, but I don't want to put you down that road).

Comment: You are indeed correct, AJAX is a thing I've never heard of. Well, I'll keep hunting! Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what your concern is with the new page opening? This is actually very normal and acceptable :-)

Comment: I guess it's just one more thing I would have to figure out how to style and deal with. Since this is a design class more than a pure programming class, my professor is really concerned with UX. The fewer clicks necessary, the better, and I can see her being picky about needing to navigate back to the previous page to continue browsing.

Comment: It seems like a big ask from your professor that you learn how to use AJAX when it's a design oriented course.

Comment: @user3595267, check 'free contact ajax php form' on google - i am sure you will find nice examples.

Comment: You're telling me! :) She's all about self-teaching, since she herself has very little programming experience. It's pretty much the only thing that I'm still trying to figure out with my site, so I'd like to find a solution, but since this does the job, I'm tempted to just let it be and turn it in.

Comment: I'll get on that, @nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, based on what you've said the easiest would be to:

Move the contents of html_form_send.php to the top of your form page (which must be of .php extention).

Then on your form change `action="html_form_send.php"` to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']'"` this directs the form to action the same page.

Basically the action="" tag allows you to choose where the form will be submitted to, so whichever page you have in there will be called and have the form data available to it in either $_GET or $_POST (HTTP Transfer methods) depending on which you tell it to use, using method="GET" or method="POST" on the form tag.